# When does a variable add $ in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm recently learning bash and confused when a variable would add `$`. I find code like:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
echo "$n * $i = `expr $i \* $n`"
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: also, have a look at bash doc on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` *substitutes* the variable.  Writing `$i` will insert the value of `i`, no matter where you write it.

If you want to *assign* to the variable, that obviously makes no sense.

Comment: `no matter where you write it.` unless it's in single quotes.

Comment: For example, `while [ i -le 10 ]` is wrong. Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: `$a=42` is not a variable assignment even if `a` contains the name of a variable. If you try: `a=foo; $a=42` you'll find that the shell will attempt to execute a program called `foo=42`. (For a variable assignment to be recognized as such, it must have the syntax of a variable assignment before any expansions; the syntax requires what is on the left-hand side of the `=` to be a valid identifier.)

Comment: @hel: Did you understand my answer? If you want to use or compare the value, you need to substitute it.  That's what `$` does.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah! Maybe $variable is like `#define ` in C. So it works when use or compare the value. But I also want to know why `while [ i -le 10 ]` doesn't work.

Comment: @hel: Because `i` doesn't exist.  Without `$`, variables don't mean anything (except for assignment).

Answer (score 3):

I thought  [@slaks'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)  [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38570289/1620779) wouldn't be complete without this :

**When not to add `$` for a variable**

1. With The Double-Parentheses [[ Construct ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html)

   ```
   x=5;
   (( x++ )) # fine, note this construct accept $x form too.
   ```
2. When using `export`

   ```
   var=stuff
   export var #fine
   ```
3. When using `declare`

   ```
   declare -a arry # fine
   ```

**When not omit $**

As [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) pointed out in the comment below:

> you can leave out the $ in any arithmetic context, not just ((...))
>   and $((...)) ... For example, if arr is an array (not associative), then
>   ${arr[x++]} is also fine.

Consider

```
# You wanted to create an associative array 'test' but you forgot to do
# declare -A test , Now below    
test[foo]=bar # is foo a variable or a key, the reader isn't clear
# creates a simple array
echo ${test[foo]} # is foo a variable or a key?
bar
declare -p test
declare -a test='([0]="bar")'
# What happened?
# Since foo was not set at the point when 'test[foo]=bar' was called,
# bash substituted it with zero
# I meant to say test[foo]=bar hides an error.
```

Comment: you can add them inside `(())` it generally doesn't matter except in rare circumstances.

Comment: @sjsam: In bash, you can leave out the `$` in any arithmetic context, not just `((...))` and `$((...))` (which are arithmetic contexts, of course). For example, if `arr` is an array (not associative), then `${arr[x++]}` is also fine.

Comment: @rici : Thankyou, but may not recommend `${arr[x]}` for the same reason you've mentioned. it supports associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

A key thing to remember is that variables are never passed around in shell, only *values*. When you call something like

```
echo "$foo"
```

you might think that `echo` receives `$foo`, then looks at its value. Instead, the shell first *expands* `$foo` to the value of `foo`, then passes that value to `echo`.

The dollar sign is used to introduce any such *parameter expansion*, where the value of a parameter is needed. Consider:

```
$ foo=10
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo $foo
10
```

From the perspective of the `echo` command, there is *no* difference between `echo $foo` and `echo 10`; in both cases, the value passed to `echo` is 10.

Answer (score 0):

To set a value to a variable in bash you can do
**a=10**
Where as to access the value of that variable you need to use
**echo $a** which mean $ is a symbol used to access the value of a variable.

```
i=1                     ---> setting variable as 1
while [ $i -le 10 ]     ---> simple while statement which loops till value of i is less that 10
do
echo "$n * $i = `expr $i \* $n`" ---> This is a syntax error bcoz value of n is never assigned
i=`expr $i + 1`         ---> This line add's one to value of i
done                    ---> terminate while loop
```

Hope that explains you.